# Is it correct to say that the following code implements polymorphism in Python3?

Tags: python, polymorphism

Sorry for a pretty vague question. But I can't find a strict definition of what polymorphism is if we implement it in a function (so that this function has a common interface but accepts objects of different types).
E.g., does the following code really implement polymorphism? Can we call it so?

```py
class A:
    def func(self):
        pass


class B(A):
    pass


class C(A):
    pass


def common_interface(obj):
    obj.func()


common_interface(B())
common_interface(C())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: Yes, it is polymorphism.

---

Your classes implement textbook *subtype* polymorphism. All of `A`, `B` and `C` satisfy the interface of their common subtype `A`.

Your function implements [*structural* polymorphism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system) (Python calls this a [`Protocol`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Protocol)). It accepts *any* type with a callable `.func` attribute.

[Well implemented](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) subtype polymorphism satisfies structural polymorphism as well. Your function accepts `B` and `C` not because they satisfy `A`, but because they have a callable `.func` attribute — which they do as a result of satisfying `A`.

---

Python‘s [„duck typing“](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) naturally maps to structural typing when using objects. You can force other type semantics by checking types (e.g. via `isinstance`) or using single/multiple dispatch (e.g. via [`singledispatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) and type annotations.

For this example, your function could also use subtype polymorphism (`obj: A`) or a [sum type](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (`obj: Union[B, C]`).

Answer (score 1):

Computer scientists will tell you that there are several different types of polymorphism. The type your example refers to is the ability of a *reference* to an object to refer to different types of objects during the running of the program and when a method is invoked on that reference, the correct implementation of that method is invoked based upon the actual current type of that object. In Python, a reference to an object is simply a variable to which an object has been assigned, for example `b` in the following: `b = B()`.

**While your example strictly speaking does demonstrate polymorphism** in that you are passing two objects of different classes to `commmon_interface` and are able to invoke method `func` on these two different objects, this is not the best example since both objects share the same exact implementation of that method. The following example would be clearer to a student:

```
class B():
    def func():
        do_something_1()


class C():
    def func():
        do_something_2()


def foo(obj):
    obj.func()


foo(B())
foo(C())
```

In method `foo`, reference `obj` refers once to an object of class `B` and once to class `C` during the running of the program. When method `func` is called, two *different* implementations will be called. So while this is not a necessary feature of polymorphism, it is a better example that describes its usefulness.

**In statically-typed languages like `C++` and `Java`, polymorphism is constrained by public inheritance.** For example, if I declare `P` to be a pointer to an object of class `A`, then I can only assign to `P` references to objects of class `A` or descendants of `A` in the public inheritance hierarchy. **But in Python, with its duck typing, there is no such limitation.** Your example might suggest otherwise.

Comment: When did C gain inheritance?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Oops!

Comment: This has nothing to do with strong typing (which Python has, by the way). What you mean might be *static*/manifest typing, which easily expresses this via templating/typevars (C++), structural typing (again C++, functional languages, ...) or unions (most modern languages, also C).